# Is there a time limit on wiki tag entries?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tag-wikis

I created one entry for the [career-advice wiki tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-advice), and decided to see if I qualified to create any others. According to the "top users" link for a couple other tags, I appear in the top 20 answerers for a couple others, for example "[best practices](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/best-practices/topusers)" (oh no, I'm at the bottom of the list!). There is no edit functionality for me when I try to edit the wiki tag for best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top users page *always* shows the current user, **even if they're not in the top 20**.

[image]

Take another look at that page and count the number of users displayed. I suspect that there are 21, with you at the bottom. It can be difficult to tell - especially if you are outside the top answerers in the last 30 days as well - and I believe has been raised on Meta Stack Overflow before. If I find the link I'll update this answer.

Comment: I didn't catch that I was #21 on the list on the ones I was unable to edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are other rules aside from just being in the Top 20.

When the Tag wiki concept was launched, you also require a certain about of up votes for that tag as well:

> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain frequently asked questions about the tag and guidelines on its usage.
>
> Tag wikis can be edited by users with more than 2000 reputation, provided:
>
> - They are in the top 20 answerers for this tag or
> - They have more than 100 answer upvotes in this tag

[From Jeff](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/)

I believe the exact rules have changed since then, but I can't find the current rules to be more exact.

Comment: Rather than having just 100 up-votes you need to have the bronze tag badge which means having at least 20 non-community wiki answers as well.